# how can i get the view(item template may be) object like image or textblock from the ListView object?

Tags: windows, windows-8

Windows Metro App:

I need a way to find the center of items (or cells) of which the ListView is composed.
For example :
If i have an Image and TextBlock inside a stackpanel which populates the ListView, i want the center of that stackpanel or any object or view it contains.
(new to Windows 8)
Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that will give you the center point of an element - it takes a generic FrameworkElement so you can pass in a ListView, StackPanel, or other controls.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  Gets the center point of any element 
    /// </summary>
    private Point GetCenterPoint(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        GeneralTransform buttonTransform = element.TransformToVisual(null);

        // This gives the point in the upper left-hand corner of the element.  
        Point topLeftPoint = buttonTransform.TransformPoint(new Point());

        // Now get the center point.
        Point centerPoint = new Point();
        centerPoint.X = topLeftPoint.X + element.ActualWidth / 2;
        centerPoint.Y = topLeftPoint.Y + element.ActualHeight / 2;

        return centerPoint;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi Jennifer Marsman, that is realy close but "How do i get the Stack panel inside the listview ? As in , is it supposed to be a child of listview ? " please give some direction and thanks ..!!

Comment: You can get a reference to any element by giving it an x:Name.  Then use that value to access it programmatically from your code.  For example:         `<ListView x:Name="myListView">
            <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel">
                <Image Source="Assets/Logo.png"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="HELLO WORLD!"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListView>`  Then you can use myListView to access the ListView from your code-behind.

Comment: yes i get that but i have the stackpanel defined as a datatemplate for the listview.So when any item is clicked i can get the ListView reference from "Sender" and now after that i would need the StackPanel(you can call it a row) reference.Thats why i asked for Children property ? Do you get what i mean Jennifer ?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now.  I believe that you want `myListView.Items`.

Comment: i am not on my PC right now..il test what you have suggested and will get back to you tomorow...thank you so much jen.

Comment: Hi , i just tried using the "items" property but that returns the data source objects which were used for populating the list and not the UI Components which i want..help needed..!!

Comment: Every control that inherits from ItemControl has a property called ItemContainerGenerator. You can ask the generator for the container of a specific item. For example, you could ask ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator for the container of Customer1 and you would get back a ListBoxItem. Once you have the item, you're probably good. You can just find the center of that. If you need to keep digging you can get into the content, the data template, even particular items. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx

Comment: Having said all that, there's probably an easier way to do what you're trying to do. This question is a little unusual because normally you can position items in the DataTemplate itself. Can you help us understand what the end result is that you're trying to achieve?